# What is the benefit of oxygen tanks to persons trappped in an enclosed space?

Tags: human-physiology, respiration

When people are enclosed in an air-tight space, the levels of carbon dioxide will rise to lethal levels (hypercapnia) long before the oxygen is exhausted (hypoxia).  For example, the astronauts of Apollo 13 were in danger because the carbon dioxide scrubbers in the lunar module were inadequate.  They never "ran out of oxygen", even though the oxygen tank of their service module exploded.

What would be the benefit to supplying such persons with tanks of additional oxygen?  It seems to be a futile gesture to me.

The reason I ask is a news story ongoing for several weeks.  Twelve children and one adult have been trapped by water in a cave for several weeks.  At the time this question was written, four boys were already rescued.  Officials have repeatedly expressed concerns that the "oxygen is running out" and are placing oxygen tanks in the cave.  Is there any benefit to this, or are officials simply ignorant of human physiology?

Comment: By breathing oxygen from a tank you can reduce hypercapnia. As Astrolamb below also indicates; O2 eliminates CO2 from the body; it's a balance

Comment: The quantity of CO2 is less important than concentration. By increasing the quantities of O2, you decrease the concentration of CO2, thus reducing hypercapnia.

Comment: @AliceD: That's a great solution, *until your tank runs out*.  Then you are back to breathing the ambient air, which now has *even more* CO2 than you started with!

Comment: @DrSheldon, alas yet obviously, nothing in existence today lasts eternally

Comment: @Astrolamb: Increasing the amount of O2 (or other gases) would hypothetically work, but wouldn't it be far more efficient (e.g. doubling the ambient air volume to halve the pCO2) and practical to use a CO2 scrubber?

Comment: CO2 scrubbers are very costly compared to the relative ease by which oxygen is generated. Additionally, they are far more efficient when scrubbing high concentrations of CO2, such as exhaust gases, than the lower concentrations of ambient CO2.

Comment: The big issue in the case of the cave is that it is a temporary thing. O2 only needs to be supplied until the trapped people are rescued, and scrubbers are too expensive relative to O2 costs to be used for such a temporary situation. This is hugely different from, say, the ISS, which is intended for long-term occupation. For the ISS, using scrubbers is much more practical.

Comment: @Astrolamb, good answer - you might as well compile your comments into a full-blown answer, makes perfect sense. Just add a few web links here and there and it would receive my upvote for sure.

Comment: I'd add that we don't know the dimensions, ventilation conditions, altitude, and other important aspects of the chamber in this case. A cave is a *very* different environment from a lunar module. It is certainly not air tight.

Comment: "...or are officials simply ignorant of human physiology?" You assume much.

Comment: @Astrolamb: The cost aspect is good point.  Also, oxygen tanks are more likely to be on-hand than CO2 scrubbers.  However, neither of these have to do with the "running out of oxygen" claims of the press.  Then again, during Apollo 13 the press incorrectly first reported the astronauts "running out of oxygen."

Comment: I'm confused - how does having more oxygen tanks NOT have something to do with running out of oxygen?

Comment: @Astrolamb: Do we genuinely know if the oxygen is running out?  We have press reports, but the press has been wrong before, as it was in Apollo 13.  We can't assume that the O2 concentration has actually been measured.  I have yet to read an actual value of O2 concentration, nor have scientific terms such as "hypoxia" been used.

Comment: I think that to the uninformed public, high CO2 concentrations is effectively equivalent to "running out of oxygen", so comments from the press are moot. I'm sure the officials have consulted people who actually know what they're talking about.

Comment: I don't believe they are supplying oxygen tanks to reoxygenate the cave...they are supplying oxygen tanks to be able to ferry people over 1 km underwater. They feel pressure to do this quickly because oxygen levels are dropping and presumably CO2 levels are rising in the small space the individuals are in. Separate issues, likely confused in news.

Comment: @BryanKrause that's what I thought too (the oxygen was for diving, not for the boys while they're sitting in the cave), but in [this cbc report](https://www.cbc.ca/news/world/thai-cave-rescue-nave-seal-death-oxygen-1.4736079) it sounds like they actually ran an $O_2$ line into the cave.

Comment: @DanHall Thanks for that source, I had looked briefly and didn't find ; I also had thought of natural CO2 sequestering in a cave system and I think your answer covers that well. I wonder, too, if by "oxygen line" they really just mean "compressed air" as in a typical mine ventilation system.

Comment: @BryanKrause I wouldn't be surprised if they did (mean compressed air rather than oxygen)

Comment: "They never "ran out of oxygen", even though the oxygen tank of their service module exploded." The oxygen tanks in the service module exploded, but they still had the oxygen tanks in the lunar module, which provided sufficient oxygen for the "quick return" flight path back to earth. It wasn't like they survived four days on the ambient oxygen in the cabin at the time of the accident. To sustain life you have to have both a supply of oxygen and a way of limiting $CO_2$ concentration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to answer your question. If we assume the cave is an air-tight chamber, we've entered the domain of a very specialized field in medicine, so I can't speak as authoritatively as I'd like there, but lets start, with the fact that the cave is *not* air tight.

#### It's a cave

A cave is not a submarine or a lunar module. It is not air-tight, but in a large environment with various types of gas exchange. The cave may already have it's own $CO_2$ scrubber of a sort, since [common minerals reversibly bind $CO_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide_scrubber). I expect there is a whole science around $CO_2$ cycles in, e.g., limestone caves, but the point here is there is likely a sink of some sort for the $CO_2$ produced by the boys. For example, I think we could reasonably speculate that the following equilibrium in a limestone cave would be driven to the right with additional $CO_2$:

$CaCO_3 + H_2O + CO_2 \rightleftharpoons Ca(HCO_3)_2$

#### Why would you give oxygen?

Here I can speak authoritatively. I'd refer you to both of West's excellent texts (Respiratory Physiology and Pulmonary Pathophysiology) for further reference.

Lets clear up a misconception in the comments. It is correct that we're concerned about the concentration (typically expressed as partial pressure) of gas, not the amount. It is *not* correct that $O_2$ eliminates $CO_2$ from the body. This can be confusing, but it is a misapplication of Dalton's law to human physiology, based on a misunderstanding about where and how the gas is exchanged. By Dalton's law, you can reduce the concentration of $CO_2$ *in a container* by increasing the concentration of some other gas (e.g., $O_2$). If $CO_2$ *is* accumulating in the cave (rather than being taken up by the environment), then delivering compressed gas with no $CO_2$ would decrease the concentration of $CO_2$ in inspired air. Inspired air, however, is not the same as alveolar air or arterial or venous gas, and the human body is not well modeled as a container full of various gases.

While it is true that when $CO_2$ is retained in respiratory acidosis, arterial $P_{O2}$ must go down by whatever amount arterial $P_{CO2}$ goes up, it doesn't work the other way around. Delivering a higher $F_{iO2}$, or fraction of inspired $O_2$ does *not* cause an inverse change in arterial $CO_2$. This ends up being fairly complicated, and a full discussion is beyond the scope of this question. Let me just emphasize that **supplemental $O_2$ specifically treats low $O_2$** (or, in a very specific case, $CO$, carbon**mon**oxide, poisoning). **High $CO_2$ is treated by increasing *ventilation*.** In fact, there are a few special cases where supplemental $O_2$ actually *increases* a patient's $CO_2$ levels, two of which involve hypercapnic respiratory failure. We do give $O_2$ for hypercapnic respiratory failure, but it is given to treat the associated hypoxia, *not* the hypercapnea. The only way to decrease $CO_2$ is to increase ventilation. This is a very important concept in critical care and respiratory medicine. I'd refer you to West Pulmonary Pathophysiology, Chapter 10, or any critical care textbook.

#### So, back to the reason you might want to give oxygen...

[CNN reports](https://www.cnn.com/2018/07/06/health/thai-soccer-team-oxygen-bn/index.html) that oxygen levels in the cave have reached 15%. If the atmospheric pressure of the cave is 760mm Hg, then the $P_{O2}$ in inspired air is about 107mm Hg, ((760 - 47 for water vapor) * 0.15, see West Respiratory Physiology, or any physiology text). At 600mm Hg (equivalent to an elevation of ~2000 meters) $P_{O2}$ in inspired air is 83mm Hg. This is low, and *could* start to be a problem (leading to hypoxemia and hypoxia), depending on the ability of the boys to compensate (again, see West, either respiratory physiology or pulmonary pathophysiology). **If the $O_2$ levels in the cave continued to drop, or if the boys weren't compensating well, then it would be reasonable to give supplemental oxygen to treat their hypoxia, regardless of what the $CO_2$ levels were.**

#### But if $O_2$ was low, wouldn't they also have to have high $CO_2$?

I'm not an expert in cave ecology, but it doesn't seem that strange to me that the rate of $O_2$ consumption by the boys could exceed the environment's capacity to produce or release $O_2$ from organic sources, dissolved sources, or ventilation, without their rate of $CO_2$ production overwhelming the environment's $CO_2$ sink. I have no good evidence one way or the other for this speculation.

#### What if it *is* an air-tight container?

Atmospheric $CO_2$ is on the order of [400ppm](https://www.climate.gov/news-features/understanding-climate/climate-change-atmospheric-carbon-dioxide), or 0.04%. Normal levels in the body are 5% (40mm Hg / 760). We rely on this gradient to dump the $CO_2$ produced by cellular respiration using ventilation, but can still operate, with difficulty, [with 5% $F_{iCO2}$](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16499405/). Serious problems (same reference) occur at higher levels. Again, in this particular case we're beyond my personal expertise (Dammit, Jim, I'm a doctor, not an aerospace or submarine doctor!), but in an air-tight container without a $CO_2$ sink, if $CO_2$ levels were higher than 5% and rising, I'd expect you would need to directly address $CO_2$. If it's a small container, adding other gases from pressurized canisters, or pumping gases in would decrease the $F_{iCO2}$ by Dalton's law, provided you could overcome the rate of $CO_2$ production by the boys. If $CO_2$ had accumulated in the boys blood (hypercapnea), they would (need to) increase their ventilation as well, adding more $CO_2$ to the chamber.